# JupyterLab - import module

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab

I use JupyterLab, jupyter notebook and try to import the script. The script is located in the notebook's directory.

Unfortunately import is impossible.
Error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'irt_01_generate_sample_data'
```

On the other hand:
When I run terminal and import the script, everything works fine.

What should I do to import the script ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is whether you're running the same Python (executable) and have the same paths (where it is looking for imports) in both the terminal and Jupyter Notebook:

```
import sys
sys.executable 
sys.path
```

Comment: Both terminal as well as Jupyter Notebook have paths:
'/usr/bin/python3'

Comment: I thought that if the .py file and Jupyter Notebook are in the same directory, this directory is automatically on the list to look (this rule works for terminal, pycharm IDE etc)

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it should have been `sys.path` (as now corrected in my answer). I had a similar issue earlier, check out this discussion: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1524